# Hide turtle problems

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

Am trying to create a opening screen for a pong video game.
However, am struggling to hide the turtle pen when it's going down from the center.

```
import turtle

wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.title("pong by @FakeTony")
wn.bgcolor("black")
wn.setup(width= 800, height=600)
wn.tracer(0)
#Entry board
pen = turtle.Turtle()
pen.speed(0)
pen.color("white")
pen.hideturtle()
pen.goto(0, -50)
pen.write("Created by FakeTony", align="center", font=("Courier", 24, "normal"))
pen.goto(0,0)
pen.write("Welcome To Pong", align="center", font=("Courier", 24, "normal"))



while True:
        wn.update()
```

Comment: Do you expect hiding the turtle to also lift the pen? You should use `penup()` for that; `hideturtle()` only stops the turtle itself from being rendered; it doesn't stop it from drawing a trail behind it.

Comment: (that's a guess instead of an answer because your question doesn't say clearly enough what the actual problem is; this is a place where a screenshot marked up to show what's different from the output you expect would be helpful).

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found an answer. In it, I change the

```
while True:
    wn.update()
```

into a

```
turtle.mainloop()
```

So this should be your total code:

```
import turtle

wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.title("pong by @FakeTony")
wn.bgcolor("black")
wn.setup(width=800, height=600)
wn.tracer(0)
# Entry board
pen = turtle.Turtle()
pen.speed(0)
pen.color("white")
pen.hideturtle()
pen.goto(0, -50)
pen.write("Created by FakeTony", align="center", font=("Courier", 24, "normal"))
pen.goto(0, 0)
pen.write("Welcome To Pong", align="center", font=("Courier", 24, "normal"))

turtle.mainloop()
```

Comment: I agree that that's a change the OP should make, but I don't see what it has to do with their specific stated problem. Can you explain why this change fixes the _specific_ issue of the pen "not being hidden when it's going down from the center"?

Comment: (One of the things that makes Stack Overflow different from [codereview.se] is that on SO, a question and answer set should be about _one specific problem_, with the question's code being the shortest possible thing that shows that problem, and with any code not necessary to show that problem factored out; so ideally, f/e, if the problem isn't about writing text, the OP shouldn't use `pen.write()` at all, and if they can show the problem without the `wn.update()` loop, that loop should be completely removed from the code in the question and not available to be discussed in the first place).

Comment: For your first comment Charles Duffy, No I don't, I expected the pen.goto to move the pen to the right direction. Though, what I should have asked instead was: why won't my pen hide when it's going down to write something. Thank you for explaining to me what the little box is for also.

Comment: Charles Duffy how do you stop the turtle from leaving or trail or hiding it?

Comment: You can use pen.penup()